# VBA Date + For logic

Tags: excel, vba, date, for-loop, format

can someone help me? It seems my for logic is not working at all because it keeps returning me 12:00AM for starttime 
Here is my code

```
Sub forlogic()
    Dim i As Single
    Dim totalrow As Double
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim mydate As Date

    totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    mydate = Date

    Debug.Print mydate

    mydate = mydate - 90

    Debug.Print mydate

    For i = 1 To i = rowtotal Step 2
        startdate = Format(Range("E" & i).Value, "short date")
        startdate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

        If mydate > startdate Then
            Range("M" & i).Value = "Expired"
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next i
    Debug.Print startdate
End Sub
```

it keeps returning me

12:00:00 AM  for startdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is tested and working as expected. List of updates:

1) To refer to sheet, `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` which I dimmed as `ws`
2) Updated `totalrow` calculation
3) Since you are only acting on one outcome of the `IF` statement, you can condense to 1 line.
4) Add `Option Explicit` to catch errors like swapping `totalrow` with `rowtotal`  (This **also** would have caught your sheet reference error)
5) Adjusted the i increment (this defaults to 1, no need to state `Step 1`)

This is tested and working fine on my end.

```
Option Explicit

Sub forlogic()
Dim totalrow As Long, i As Long
Dim startdate As Date, mydate As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

totalrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mydate = Date - 90

For i = 1 To totalrow
    startdate = Format(ws.Range("E" & i).Value2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    If mydate > startdate Then ws.Range("M" & i).Value = "Expired"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @JéssicaSartori - If this did the trick and solved your issue, please mark as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  This will also remove the question from the Unanswered queue.  Thanks!

Comment: My mistake was on the For condition I was doing "For i = 1 To i = rowtotal" and it should be: "For i = 1 To rowtotal"