# Range Right and Left Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

What I am actually trying to do is just filter the information on my pivot table. The problem I am getting is that when I group the data by months it groups all the months regardless if they are in the same year or not. I accept any advice on how to fix that in a simpler way. 
My current roundabout is the code below, which is also not working. 
All I am doing there is applying the right and left formulas in ranges, so I can get the years and months in different columns and then filter by that.

Cans someone please help me with this issue? Thank you so much!

```
All.Range("L" & endprivate + 1, "L" & total5).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
All.Range("U1").Value = "Year for Pivot Table"
All.Range("V1").Value = "Month for Pivot Table"
All.Range("U" & (endprivate + 1), "U" & total5) = Right(All.Range("L" & (endprivate + 1), "L" & total5), 2)
All.Range("V" & (endprivate + 1), "V" & total5) = Left(All.Range("L" & endprivate + 1, "L" & total5), 3)
```

Comment: I suspect you just need more practice with the pivot table's grouping feature.  I can say that because the same thing drove me crazy for a long time. I assume you're giving the pivot table a column of dates and one or more columns of data?

Comment: Yes!!!! and I need to date be grouped by ex.: jun-2018 and jun-2016 not just jun

Comment: Post a screen shot of what you're doing. It's probably easy to fix if we can see it.

Comment: @JéssicaSartori please note that if you get an answer that works, please click the check to accept it. Looks like when you asked a question previously you just said you loved the author (which I'm sure he appreciated). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050039/vba-date-for-logic

Comment: So when you're grouping, does selecting both "Months" and "Years" not give what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### <sub>[image: Pivot Tables:]</sub>   <sup>*Let Excel do the work for you!*</sup>

> <sub>I had a question a while back on a different forum where someone who had been using Excel for a few months, proudly told me that his spreadsheet get daily inspections, since he's going through it cell by cell every day anyhow, to calculate the averages - ***using a calculator.***</sub>
>
> <sub>True story.  He has very impressed when I showed him that *Excel can even do **averages***.  It's not his fault - there's no way he could have known of all of the features until someone told him....</sub> :-)

Pivot tables are one of the most underappreciated and underused features in Excel, giving the most flexibility in data reporting with the least amount of effort -- once you become aware of what it can do for you.  This is only one little feature:

---

When your pivot table is grouping dates in ways you don't want it to, you can choose to re-group in several ways.

1. First, click anywhere **within the date column** of your Pivot Table
2. Click the `Analyze` (pivot-table specific) tab on the ribbon.
3. In the **`Groups` Group**, click **`Ungroup`**.  *(lol)*

   [image: img]
4. Next, click `Group Field` (if it's not enabled, click on a date again)

   [image: img2]
5. Here you can ***Select or Deselect multiple items as needed**.

   For example, you said you had issue with it grouping months across multiple years -- so **you would select `Months` and `Years`** and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Experimenting with it may be the best way to learn. There are infinite possibile ways to arrange the same data with the many layers of options that are built-in.

---

### **Endless possibilities**

There are other options available through the context (right-click) menu, as well as on the `Design` ribbon tab (which appears when you click on the pivot table).

[image: img toolbar]

---

**Just a couple variations of basic arrangements under `Report Layout`:**

[image: img]

[image: img]

---

### The right function for the job

Lastly, if you do still need to refer to specific data in your pivot table from else where in the workbook, instead of using text functions (like `RIGHT` and `MID`), use the function meant for the job:

- [**Excel's `GETPIVOTDATA` function**](https://support.office.com/article/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f)!

---

## More Information:

- Microsoft : [**Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)
- Microsoft : [**Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)
- Wikipedia : [**Pivot Tables**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table)
- Microsoft : [**`GETPIVOTDATA` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f)
- ExcelJet : [**How to use Excel's `GETPIVOTDATA` Function**](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-getpivotdata-function)

---

### Advanced Pivot Table Tips:

- TutsPlus : [**How To Make Use of 5 Advanced Excel Pivot Table Techniques**](https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-excel-pivot-table-techniques--cms-28572)
- ExcelJet : [**23 things you should know about Excel pivot tables**](https://exceljet.net/things-to-know-about-excel-pivot-tables)
- ExcelChamps : [**Top 31 Pivot Table Tips & Tricks for Advanced Excel Users**](https://excelchamps.com/blog/pivot-table-tips-tricks/)

Comment: Thank you!!! I think my mistake was that I was selecting first the months and then the years! I tried to do it again and not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about trying to manually manipulate the data, it's always best to leave dates as Dates and adjust the way you see them.

1. **Add** the ***Date*** field as a ***Column*** in the pivot table.
2. **Right click** on any ***date***.
3. **Click Group...**

[image]

4. Select both **Months** & **Years**

[image]

5. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: That is what I was doing. But I am sure my data only has information from 2016 to 2018 and when I select months and years, it gives me years like 19001... to 2019 which does not make any sense!

Comment: Then the data is wrong, or Excel isn't recognizing it properly because of the way it's entered/formatted.  You need to find the outliers, and fix them.  The easiest way to find the outliers is to add a filter to the original data, and see what values aren't listed under the years 2016-2018.